# How to analyze code from other class than currently analyzed in SonarQube?

Tags: java, plugins, sonarqube

**Case:** I'm writing SonarQube rule that needs to check if manually created object is being closed. When it's not, issue should be raised.

Let's assume that part related to determining if object is created manually (or not) is easy and not relevant. For purpose of this example it'll be constructor call. However, there are other ways to instantiate that kind of object, which are not eligible for closing.

These are cases I would like to cover. Let's assume we have following class:

```java
public class MyType {
    public void close() {
        //close
    }
}
```

This is the first case. Simple one:

```java
public class ClassOne {

    public void methodA() {
        MyType z = null;
        try {
            z = new MyType();
            // do sth
        } finally {
            z.close(); // correct use
        }
    }

    public void methodB() {
        MyType z = new MyType();
        // do sth
        // incorrect use, should be closed here
    }
}
```

Second one, a bit more tricky:

```java
public class ClassOne {

    MyType creator() {
        return new MyType();
    }

    MyType jump() {
        return creator();
    }

    public void methodA() {
        MyType z = null;
        try {
            z = jump();
            // do sth
        } finally {
            z.close(); // correct use
        }
    }

    public void methodB() {
        MyType z = jump();
        // do sth
        // incorrect use, should be closed here
    }
}
```

Third case, one I'm not able to handle:

```java
public class ClassOne {

    public void methodA() {
        MyType z = null;
        try {
            z = new ClassTwo().creator();
            // do sth
        } finally {
            z.close(); // correct use
        }
    }

    public void methodB() {
        MyType z = new ClassTwo().creator();;
        // do sth
        // incorrect use, should be closed here
    }
}


public class ClassTwo {
    MyType creator() {
        return new MyType();
    }
}
```

To sum it up. I already implemented first and second case. I have problem with third one, since I don't know how to jump to method declaration of other class to analyze if it creates object manually.

What is the correct way to implement it? Is it possible? (using available API of course)

**Both of the analyzed classes belong to the same project and are included into project analysis.**

Comment: The down vote is not mine (obviously :) ) but I find this question somewhat unclear. What exactly do you mean by _manual creation_? A constructor call? What's `SomeExternalClass`? Something outside the codebase under analysis? Where's the `finally` block? Can you give examples of these objects being properly closed?

Comment: @toniedzwiedz Hey :-), thanks for sharing your doubts regarding question. I elaborated more on these. Hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is : with the currently available API you can't solve your third case.

Now for the more detailed answer : 
How does sonarqube java plugin runs its analysis for now : it works source file (aka `CompilationUnit`) by source file and read bytecode for symbols out of this source to resolve them *even if the source for these symbols are available for the analyzer*. This is a current limitation : Sources are analyzed in isolation from one another.

This means that, as of today, you are able to know which method is called in your source but you do not have access to the code of that method from the API if it is defined outside your source.

There are plans to make this limitation go away at some point but this is not scheduled for now.

There might be some workaround but that will be hacking around and it is probably really complex (you can "inline" some bytecode instructions or try to read and parse the source you're interested in) so I won't recommend those.